# Does the molecules in nerve cell membrane change 100% during the life of the nerve cell?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, neuroscience, neurophysiology, cell-membrane

In their lifespan nerve cells do not divide and so they stay the same. They do get damaged sometimes and require some maintenance and change their axons a bit. They also require a lot of energy so they take in stuff and produce waste. This would in my opinion mean that the molecules in nerve cell membrane can change and that molecules do go in and out, but it does not imply that there is a process which changes the molecules in nerve cell membrane regularly. I have not been able to find information whether the molecules which make up the nerve cell's membrane change 100% during its life.

**So does a nerve cell which can live 80 years change the molecules that make up the membrane regularly, so that in a long period of time almost every molecule in the membrane has changed?** This would be an analogy about a human which replaces skin cells regularly.

In addition, I would be interested if nerve cells change replace other parts inside the membrane regularly in a molecule level.

In not long living cells, which divide I think that the molecules in the membrane have to change completely. If one cell divides into two, then the amount of membrane cannot be enough in neither of the cells so they need to take in stuff and grow the membrane. In this process even if the membrane may not be regularly replaced the dividing would cause the change eventually after a lot of dividing.

Comment: Hi Lauri, welcome :) maybe the genetic mutations accumulated over time due to environmental and physiological factors could make the 80 year old neuron express the wrong proteins for the membrane, or simply not produce them at all? A neurobiologist might appear and chip in at some point with a better idea.

Comment: @pawelekzzz Thank you! That is probably true. Changes in the neuron's gene could cause different proteins in the membrane and basically also to start the neuron to change the molecules in the membrane or stop replacing them. However, I don't see directly how this is relevant to my question. Or was your point that it could be at least theoretically possible that the molecules would change if there would be a certain genetic mutation?

Comment: I meant that at least the number of molecules related to membrane proteins that will
be regularly synthesized during the lifecycle of the neuron will be part of that percent. They will also change over time themselves (or entirely stop being expressed) after accumulating mutations that affect translational regulation.

Damage to membrane phospholipids measuring ~1 nm or less will be thermodynamically rearranged using existing phospholipids. Larger damage will be resealed through exo-endocytotic vesicle trafficking but those “lost” phospholipids will be recycled through a salvage pathway.